# Flask hello world app not working in Spyder or Canopy

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I have the following Flask app, and it is returning a 404 error. I have tried it in Spyder and Enthought Canopy, and have also used the

```
set FLASK_APP
```

and

```
flask run
```

commands at cmd, with Windows 10.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/admin")
def hello_world():
   return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host="localhost", port=int("5000"))
```

Comment: not sure what your question is but assuming you have a .py file with your server code inside simply write in console "python server.py"

Comment: I tried running it with Spyder and Canopy, as well as on the command line as you said, and it returns a 404 error each time.

Comment: Not too sure about your declaration of the port, havent used it this way. you could simply try port=5000 without any parsing. maybe give that a shot :) edit when you try to start the server via cmd what is the output?

Comment: Output is always  * Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit). Changed the port declaration as you said, still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out whats wrong with your code.

You only have declared an admin route.

Accessing [localhost:5000/admin](http://localhost:5000/admin) gives you your desired output!

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your setup, for me it works just fine

Comment: I'll try it on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

try changing`@app.route('/admin') to @app.route('/')`

Comment: still returning a 404

Comment: change  ```app.run(host="localhost",port=int("5000"))``` to ```app.run()```